# Passing variable through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to pass variable using link_to so that i can display the variable in another page in rails application.I have a variable named user which i want to pass. Here is snippet of code i am using.

```
<% user = "Ram";%>
<%=link_to "Message",messages_new_path(:name=>user)%>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in your view with the link:

```
<%= link_to "Test", test_example_path(example.id, :user => "Ram") %>
```

for the purposes of demonstrating that this works, in the view associated with the path that you link_to:

```
<%= params %>
```

produces this output (the way I set it up)

```
{"user"=>"Ram", "action"=>"test", "controller"=>"example", "id"=>"2"}
```

You also have to make sure the 'test' function is created in the controller & that the routes file is set up properly.

```
 resources :examples do
    member { get :test}  
  end
```

I am not sure if this will be helpful, though, since you may not want the actual name in the code. In my experience, this information would be passed into the view from the controller, so you would have access to it in the link_to. For example,

```
<%= link_to "Message", new_message_path(user.id) %>
```